# maximum size of bss and data

Tags: c, linux

I want to declare all the variables in my C program at compile time, like for example:

```
char cache[CACHE_SIZE];
char udp_ring[MAX_UDP_PACKET_SIZE*MAX_REQUESTS];
int  num_packets;
char error_codes[NUM_ERRORS][MAX_ERROR_STRING]= {
    {"Unknown user\n"},
    {"Wrong password\n"},
    ....
};
```

The question is, are there any limits on the size of the variables in a C program when they go in BSS or DATA segment?
For example if I declare CACHE_SIZE of 8GB of RAM, will it work? Is there any difference for 32 bits or 64 bits? I plan to run the program on Linux and there will be no restriction in my RLIMIT_DATA configuration.

Comment: "I want to declare all the variables in my C program at compile time" - so there's a way declaring them at runtime?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to link with glibc, so I need to avoid malloc()

Comment: **sigh** - declaring a variable is not what you think it is. You can't declare a variable at runtime. Go grab a C book.

Comment: A variable in `C` is declared in the source code and doesn't have any direct representation in  it's compiled object (.obj) code.

Comment: I'm not able to test this at the moment (machine is not good enough), but I think on a 64bit platform with enough RAM it will work. It's only BSS.

Comment: @H2CO3 I believe OP wishes to *statically allocate* all the variables in the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will be able to manage as much virtual memory as your kernel allows processes to handle : it will depend on the architecture.

For example, on a x86 architecture (without x86-64 long mode), Linux splits by default the virtual memory seen by a process in 3GB for the process and 1GB for the kernel (even if PAE is enabled) : your process won't be able to handle more than 3GB of virtual memory (include text sections, data, bss, heap, stack, shared objects, etc.)

If you allocate all your buffer statically and the kernel cannot fit it in the process virtual address space, it will be killed at start-up : using a 8GB buffer will mostly result in this behavior on a 32-bit architecture.

If you don't want to rely on glibc's memory management function (`malloc`, ...), you could roll your own memory management library and force your process to use it with a `LD_PRELOAD` trick, that way you could define a `malloc/calloc/realloc/free` (using `sbrk()`) implementation matching your own requirements.

Comment: ok, as I understood there is no limit for statically allocated variables in 64bit mode would it be intialized (BSS) or not initialized (DATA), correct?

Comment: There *is* a  virtual limit on 64-bits architectures, which would be 2^64 bytes (16 exabytes) of virtual address space minus some space reserved to address the kernel. However, current implementations of x86-64 (AMD and Intel) are limited to 48 bits of address bits (~256 TB of virtual address space), but I'm pretty sure you'll run out of physical RAM before reaching this limit. IIRC Linux allows 128TB of virtual address space per process on x86-64.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to link with `glibc`, you should find some weird ways to be able to do [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man page). Any application has to do some syscalls (e.g. [open(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html), [read(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) ...). Glibc is also used to provide a C interface to syscalls. The [assembly howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) explains how to call syscalls without libc, directly using some assembly code (e.g. thru C `asm` instructions). See also the obsolete [_syscall(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/_syscall.2.html) man page. Look also for [VDSO](http://blogs.igalia.com/aperez/2009/01/13/the-story-of-linux-gatevdsoso/).

You can change your address space using the [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `munmap(2)` syscalls. This is the elementary operations for allocating and releasing memory. Glibc uses them to implement `malloc` and `free`.

Declaring all variables as global or static, be it initialized (`.data` segment) or cleared (`.bss` segment) has a significant disadvantage: you cannot use dynamically memory resources. And having a lot of initialized data have a significant cost: your ELF executable would be huge.

But you really should explain why you want to avoid Glibc. It is hard to avoid it when coding in C. You could use lighter alternatives like [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/).

Comment: thanks, very useful info. I want to avoid glibc because I will be distributing the program in binary form, and I don't want to have incompatibility issues with different linux distributions. Actually I will be using dynamic allocation, but it will be only for cache with my own heap management routines, I just wanted to know the limits for the other variables.

Comment: You might consider statically linking the Glibc, but this is usually a bad idea. You should explain what kind of program you are coding. Did you consider to make it a free software (e.g. GPL licensed)? And even statically linking your Glibc wont avoid all incompatibilities; some of Glibc depend slightly of the kernel version...